# Видимость элементов StackPanel

Tags: wpf, stackpanel

Есть такой контейнер:

```
<StackPanel Name="stackPanelMain">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="700" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Name="Button1">
            .....
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Name="Button2">
            .....
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Name="Button3">
            .....
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Name="Image1">
            <Image Source="...." />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Управляю отображением `stackPanelMain` через свойство `Visibility`. Все кнопки имеют собственные обработчики и появляются в зависимости от условий. `StackPanel` с картинкой висит всегда на `ZIndex` выше чем остальные и отображается всегда.

Сам вопрос. Почему при изменении свойства `Visibility` на `Hidden` у материнской `StackPanel` дочерние продолжают отображаться? А именно отображается `StackPanel` с картинкой. Другие элементы в других панелях при инициализации приложения выключаются и возможно тоже будут отображаться при включении видимости элемента (не проверял).

Спасибо.

Comment: Можете привести такой пример, чтобы я вставил себе в студию и посмотрел? Без всяких додумываний.

Comment: Ошибку нашёл с помощью временной кнопки-триггера видимости панели. Оказалось, что неправильно работал обработчик события на эту панель.